# SAML Tableau server configuration with Componentspace

Tags: asp.net-mvc, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, tableau-api, component-space

I am trying to configure tableau server as SP using componentsapce SAML.

IDP is my mvc web application and SP as tableau server.

I have created metadata using the sample code they are providing. But it ends up wit this error

' HTTP Status 500 - org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.MetadataProviderException: No IDP was configured, please update included metadata with at least one IDP '.

Am stuck and any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Anish.

Comment: try posting on the forums at tableausoftware.com

Comment: In vain.. I have first posted there and no response..

Comment: Then you can open a support request with Tableau at http://www.tableausoftware.com/support/request They are usually pretty good about response time. The form sort of forces you to search for an existing answer before submitting a new ticket, but if you press continue you can get your question to support person.